# pandas DataFrame Dividing a column by itself

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I filled with this:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
test = web.get_data_yahoo('QQQ')
```

The dataframe looks like this in iPython:

```
In [13]:  test
Out[13]:
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    DatetimeIndex: 729 entries, 2010-01-04 00:00:00 to 2012-11-23 00:00:00
    Data columns:
    Open         729  non-null values
    High         729  non-null values
    Low          729  non-null values
    Close        729  non-null values
    Volume       729  non-null values
    Adj Close    729  non-null values
    dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)
```

When I divide one column by another, I get a float64 result that has a satisfactory number of decimal places.  I can even divide one column by another column offset by one, for instance `test.Open[1:]/test.Close[:]`, and get a satisfactory number of decimal places.  When I divide a column by itself offset, however, I get just 1:

```
In [83]: test.Open[1:] / test.Close[:]
Out[83]:

    Date
    2010-01-04         NaN
    2010-01-05    0.999354
    2010-01-06    1.005635
    2010-01-07    1.000866
    2010-01-08    0.989689
    2010-01-11    1.005393
...
In [84]: test.Open[1:] / test.Open[:]
Out[84]:
    Date
    2010-01-04   NaN
    2010-01-05     1
    2010-01-06     1
    2010-01-07     1
    2010-01-08     1
    2010-01-11     1
```

I'm probably missing something simple.  What do I need to do in order to get a useful value out of that sort of calculation?  Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: I think the OP's primary concern is with the division, not the shift. The answers provided so far both address only the latter.

Comment: My concern was with the division, but the reason I'm getting that result is because of pandas alignment.  Shift resolves that issue.

Comment: Okay, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to do operations between the column and lagged values, you should be doing something like `test.Open / test.Open.shift()`.
`shift` realigns the data and takes an optional number of periods.

Comment: Aah, shift is what i needed.  I worked it out with .values, but this is the way I'd rather do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may not be getting what you think you are when you do `test.Open[1:]/test.Close`.  Pandas matches up the rows based on their index, so you're still getting each element of one column divided by its corresponding element in the other column (not the element one row back).  Here's an example:

```
>>> print d
   A  B   C
0  1  3   7
1 -2  1   6
2  8  6   9
3  1 -5  11
4 -4 -2   0
>>> d.A / d.B
0    0.333333
1   -2.000000
2    1.333333
3   -0.200000
4    2.000000
>>> d.A[1:] / d.B
0         NaN
1   -2.000000
2    1.333333
3   -0.200000
4    2.000000
```

Notice that the values returned are the same for both operations.  The second one just has `nan` for the first one, since there was no corresponding value in the first operand.

If you really want to operate on offset rows, you'll need to dig down to the numpy arrays that underpin the pandas DataFrame, to bypass pandas's index-aligning features.  You can get at these innards with the `values` attribute of a column.

```
>>> d.A.values[1:] / d.B.values[:-1]
array([-0.66666667,  8.        ,  0.16666667,  0.8       ])
```

Now you really are getting each value divided by the one before it in the other column.  Note that here you have to explicitly slice the second operand to leave off the last element, to make them equal in length.

So you can do the same to divide a column by an offset version of itself:

```
>>> d.A.values[1:] / d.A.values[:-1]
45: array([-2.   , -4.   ,  0.125, -4.   ])
```